# Merge dictionaries retaining values for duplicate keys

Tags: python, merge, duplicates

Given n dictionaries, write a function that will return a unique dictionary with a list of values for duplicate keys.

Example:

```
d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
d2 = {'c': 3, 'b': 4}
d3 = {'a': 5, 'd': 6}
```

result:

```
>>> newdict
{'c': 3, 'd': 6, 'a': [1, 5], 'b': [2, 4]}
```

My code so far:

```
>>> def merge_dicts(*dicts):
...     x = []
...     for item in dicts:
...         x.append(item)
...     return x
...
>>> merge_dicts(d1, d2, d3)
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 3, 'b': 4}, {'a': 5, 'd': 6}]
```

What would be the best way to produce a new dictionary that yields a list of values for those duplicate keys?

Comment: `d1= ['a':1, 'b':2]` Is wrong syntax for Dictionary it should be `d1= {'a':1, 'b':2}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def merge_dicts(*dicts):
    d = {}
    for dict in dicts:
        for key in dict:
            try:
                d[key].append(dict[key])
            except KeyError:
                d[key] = [dict[key]]
    return d
```

This retuns:

```
{'a': [1, 5], 'b': [2, 4], 'c': [3], 'd': [6]}
```

There is a slight difference to the question. Here all dictionary values are lists. If that is not to be desired for lists of length 1, then add:

```
    for key in d:
        if len(d[key]) == 1:
            d[key] = d[key][0]
```

before the `return d` statement. However, I cannot really imagine when you would want to remove the list. (Consider the situation where you have lists as values; then removing the list around the items leads to ambiguous situations.)

Answer (score 12):

Python provides a simple and fast solution to this: the [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) in the `collections` module. From the examples in the documentation:

> Using `list` as the `default_factory`, it is easy to group a sequence of
>   key-value pairs into a dictionary of lists:
>
> >>> s = [('yellow', 1), ('blue', 2), ('yellow', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1)]
>    >>> d = defaultdict(list)
>    >>> for k, v in s:
>     ...     d[k].append(v)
>     ...
>    >>> d.items()
>   [('blue', [2, 4]), ('red', [1](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)), ('yellow', [1, 3])]
>
> When each key is encountered for the first time, it is not already in
>   the mapping; so an entry is automatically created using the
>   `default_factory` function which returns an empty list. The
>   `list.append()` operation then attaches the value to the new list. When
>   keys are encountered again, the look-up proceeds normally (returning
>   the list for that key) and the `list.append()` operation adds another
>   value to the list.

In your case, that would be roughly:

```
import collections

def merge_dicts(*dicts):
    res = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for d in dicts:
        for k, v in d.iteritems():
            res[k].append(v)
    return res

>>> merge_dicts(d1, d2, d3)
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [1, 5], 'c': [3], 'b': [2, 4], 'd': [6]})
```