# Merging 2 dictionaries and saving translation dictionary for the overridden values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, merge

I merge 2 dictionaries, say `d1` and `d2` by:

```
d1.update(d2)
```

i.e I have:

```
d1 = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}
d2 = {1:'a', 2:'g', 4:'x'}
```

then after `d1.update(d2)` I have:

```
{1: 'a', 2: 'g', 3: 'c', 4: 'x'}
```

So the original `2:'b'` vanished so I'd like to have the translation 'b':'g' somehow, meaning the output will be the following dictionary:

```
{'b':'g'}
```

Is there any simple code to keep the overridden values?

Comment: I don't understand. What's your desired output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge dictionaries retaining values for duplicate keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745181/merge-dictionaries-retaining-values-for-duplicate-keys)

Comment: @Aran-Fey In my example I'd like to output a dictionary which contains {'b':'g'}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `{"b":"g}` is what you truly wants, you can first use dict comprehension to create it before the `update`:

```
d1 = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}
d2 = {1:'a', 2:'g', 4:'x'}

ot = {v : d2[k] for k,v in d1.items() if k in d2 and v != d2[k]}
print (ot)

d1.update(d2)
print (d1)
```

Result:

```
{'b': 'g'}
{1: 'a', 2: 'g', 3: 'c', 4: 'x'}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the keys that exist in both dictionaries
2. Create a new dictionary mapping the values from `d1` to the values from `d2`
3. Remove those key:value pairs where the key and the value are identical

```
d1 = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}
d2 = {1:'a', 2:'g', 4:'x'}

shared_keys = d1.keys() & d2
mapping = {d1[key]: d2[key] for key in shared_keys}
mapping = {k: v for k, v in mapping.items() if k != v}

print(mapping)  # output: {'b': 'g'}
```